# WPF binding to Ancestor Source

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, tooltip

I'm trying to show a `ToolTip` with the hovered image but with different dimensions.

I tried this:

```
<Image Source="c:\Pictures\Airplane.jpg" Width="50" Height="50">
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <Image Width="300" Height="300" 
               Source="{Binding Path=Source, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Image, AncestorLevel=1}}
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

The above makes a bigger image on hover but the image content is blank, probably the binding didn't work.

After hours I think I need help... what am I missing?

<sub>I don't want other solutions to the problem like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564709/wpf-on-mouse-hover-on-a-particular-control-increase-its-size-and-overlap-on-th) as I'm only trying to practice my binding skills, thanks.</sub>

Comment: So what's the `BindingExpression` error in your debug window?

Comment: @DHN, never heard on such a thing, how can I see it?

Comment: Well if you have a look in your debug output window of your Visual Studio (VS > Debug > Windows > Output) you can see a lots of output. The `BindingExpression` error will also appear there. It's not much, but you will get an idea what may be wrong.

Comment: @DHN, _"Could not find source..."_ not much indeed. thanks anyway.

Comment: One thing also for tracking binding errors is: You can supply a Flag to your bindings to make the debug output more informative. '{Binding Path=Something, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i got it to work, my initial thought was correct: `RelativeSource` won't work because the tooltip is not part of the visual tree. I thought `ElementName` would work, but it seems WPF creates a new name namescope of  some sort (not sure). So the only way to get it to work, was to use the `DataContext` as "proxy" between the two visual trees. You could also use a viewmodel with the proper informations.

```
<Image x:Name="myImage" Source="c:\Pictures\Airplane.jpg" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Width="50" Height="50">
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <Image Width="300" Height="300" Source="{Binding Path=Source}"/>
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't help, and telling the truth, I can't understand why it should have.

Comment: Ok, then try something completely different. I think it won't work because RelativeSource can't find the Image, because its not a logical parent. I update my answer and see if that works.

Comment: Actually no, i was sure it worked because we did something similar. I'm testing it right now because now i'm hooked :)

Comment: @makc  sorry that was my fault. He commented on my answer when it was wrong. I completely changed it, which unfortunately makes the comments out of context. :/

Comment: @Makc & dowhilefor. Let's delete our comments.

Comment: Thanks, that datacontext as a proxy is the most "hacky" thing I saw, but it's cool... :) thanks.